# Arc length parameterization of a list of points?

Tags: list-manipulation, computational-geometry, geometry

Suppose I have a curve represented by a list of points in the form $\{\{x_0, y_0\}, \{x_1, y_1\}, ...\}$. How to generate a list of numbers $\{s_0, s_1, ...\}$ where $s_i$ is the distance of ith point from the starting point of the list, with $s_0 = 0$?

This is basically a discrete version of arc length parameterization. Thanks.

Comment: How is the curve going to be interpolated from the samples? Just linearly?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, between a pair of neighboring points the curve is assumed to be linear, just like a segment.

Comment: Please add the code you have already tried, and the results obtained.

Comment: Accumulate@Prepend[Norm /@ Differences@list, 0]

Comment: @bbgodfrey I can easily write this in C++, but don't know how to write it in Mathematica's functional style.

Comment: @bbgodfrey would be something like: for(int i = 1; i < points.length; ++i) s[i] = s[i-1] + dist(points[i-1], points[i]);

Comment: @george2079 Hi George, thanks! Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it and close this question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a list of points,

```
points = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 6.3, .5}];
ListLinePlot[points, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

[image]

The distance between the first two points is

```
EuclideanDistance[points[[1]], points[[2]]]
(* 0.692711 *)
```

The distance between all successive pairs of points is,

```
EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[points, 2, 1]
(* {0.692711, 0.617314, 0.523778, 0.507719, 0.588738, 0.677622, \
0.701405, 0.64409, 0.546553, 0.500346, 0.560539, 0.656949} *)
```

If we tack a 0 onto the beginning of that list, then we can get a running total with `Accumulate`,

```
Accumulate[Prepend[EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[points, 2, 1], 0]]
(* {0, 0.692711, 1.31003, 1.8338, 2.34152, 2.93026, 3.60788, \
4.30929, 4.95338, 5.49993, 6.00028, 6.56081, 7.21776} *)
```

We can compare the approximate result with the exact result via

```
Show[Plot[Sqrt[2] EllipticE[x, 1/2], {x, 0, 6.3}],
 ListPlot[
  Accumulate[
   Prepend[EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[points, 2, 1], 0]], 
  DataRange -> {0, 6.3}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively: `FoldList[Plus, 0, EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[points, 2, 1]]`

Comment: @JasonB. I think you want `DataRange -> {0, 6}`, since the original set of x coordinates actually go from 0 to 6 in steps of 0.5. (See the new edit of my post: your points lie almost exactly on top of the exact curve.)

Comment: @march Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version that uses an `InterpolatingFunction` and integrates it. It is markedly slower than JasonB's answer but possibly more accurate (although not on this data).

```
s[t_] := NIntegrate[Sqrt[1 + D[Interpolation[points][tp], tp]^2], {tp, 0, t}]
```

Then, to compare to JasonB's answers:

```
Show[
 Plot[Sqrt[2] EllipticE[x, 1/2], {x, 0, 6.3}],
 ListPlot[Table[{t, s[t]}, {t, 0, 6., 0.525}], PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.03]],
 ListPlot[
   Accumulate[Prepend[EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[points, 2, 1], 0]], 
   DataRange -> {0, 6}, PlotStyle -> Red
  ]
]
```

[image]

If I could find a way of folding the operation on the `InterpolatingFunction` into the `InterpolatingFunction` itself, this would be much faster, because you can `Integrate` `InterpolatingFunction`s directly, since they're just pasted together polynomials.